# bootstrap navbar doesn't work properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my bootstrap navbar, when it's full screen a small icon-bar appear on top, and when resizing the window the same icon-bar remain there and the button doesn't appear, first here's the code:

```
<header>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?p=la">Movies List</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?p=gl">Genre List</a></li>

            </ul>
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="admin/index.php?p=log">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are u using Java Script for that functionality for Nav Bar

`<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->` This requires Java Script Import that and it should work

Comment: I'm using bootstrap plugins <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be missing the javascript component include:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery as well, if not you will need to. Can you provide the script includes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue from your Javascript with CSS, Button is always reflecting which means your Nav Bar is not converting as Button when image is enlarged

**You can use this its easy and convenient** [Boot Flat](http://bootflat.github.io/)

Comment: yes it's included too, I come to realise that the problem is that javascript doesn't work on my website at all, I don't know what prevent it from working.

Comment: Okay Try using Boot Flat [link](http://bootflat.github.io/) it have all the JavaScript included in the folder u can modify accordigly . Let me know if any help!!